# remove tabindex -1 from views accordion

Tags: views, navigation

the view accordion is automatically assinging a tabindex -1 to header field.  like this :

```
<a href="#how_to_become_a_grantee-block-0" tabindex="-1">
```

how can I remove that tabindex -1 ? thank you

Comment: It's added with JS so you could probably remove it with the same.

Comment: I cant find where its added its not in the accordion_views. js or in the view.js  Do you know which file adds that.  I did a search and cannot find it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you want to modify the source contributed module :(.

You just write some custom CSS in your theme to target the item. In your theme.info file:

```
scripts[]=my_theme_overrides.js
```

Then in your javascript file you write the following, as an example (untested, should work, you may need to tweak it.):

```
/* in my_theme_overrides.js */
(function ($) {
  $("#how_to_become_a_grantee-block-0").removeAttr("tabindex");
})(jQuery);
```